# Sort plugins by rating

Tags: plugins, sort

When I want to install a new Wordpress plugin, I do a search for the plugin I want, and I receive a list of results.

Is there any way to sort the results by rating, or name?

If not, it would be a useful addition to Wordpress.

Comment: Useful additions are suggested here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ - you can open a ticket with an enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for plugins at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ rather than through your WordPress install you get more options on your search results.

Comment: I can not see anything especially different,..

Answer (score 6):

Well it doesn't. It was changed after year 2011 and now (in 2015) you have no options to sort on Wordpress.org or in your WordPress installation.