# Plugin search sorting for admin section - Wordpress

Tags: plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort plugins by rating](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/sort-plugins-by-rating)

Just curious if anyone knows of a plugin or a way to add sorting for Plugin searches in the Administration of a Wordpress site. I find myself searching through all kinds of plugins, ultimately just wanting to see what has the best rating or highest number of downloads.

Kind of surprised Wordpress hasn't added this feature already. Anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, I have noticed it and couldn't (at the time) find a plugin that fixed it.

My solution:

Open the [Wordpress Plugin Directory page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) and search there - you get a lot more options. Copy the plugin title over to your site's plugin admin page and search there - then install from there. It's quicker than downloading from the Plugin Directory and reuploading, but you have to watch out because sometimes the plugin titles don't correspond to your search string (the plugin search is kind of odd that way).